# Split one ID to two font types

Tags: android, layout

I have a .xml in a layout folder of an decompiled android .apk. There's a TextView element which has an ID (`android:id="@+id/x"`) In the ID is text. But I want to display the first two letters of the ID in font type bold and the text, which is left in normal font type. So, does anybody know, what I can do, to solve this  without touching the ID. An answer would be so nice. :)

Comment: If no answer is right, you need to make your question more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SpannableString to achieve this:

```
SpannableString str = new SpannableString( "abcdefg" );
str.setSpan( new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, 1, 0 );

textView.setText( str );
```

and it should give you "ab" boldfaced and rest of text unchanged.

Comment: How is this related to the question...?

Comment: To me OP wants to display "x" of "+@id/x". To be able to do that he needs to know what was the name in first place, isn't?

Comment: Uhm, well, maybe. But it's a strange question.

Comment: Okay, it seems to be really a little bit unclear. So, I'm talking about this file here. https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/jellybean/core/res/res/layout/keyguard_screen_tab_unlock.xml There's aclock and I want to display only the first two letters of the clock bold. I already created a style for the textview to change color etc. easier. Another idea was, to copy the textview and set the first to maxlenght=2, but this would be a bad solution, I think. So any ideas? Hope, it's a little bit clearer now.

Comment: it's layout file. Describe what you want :)

Comment: Okay thanks, this looks very logically. Don't blame me, but can u tell me, to which file I have to apply these lines? I just have the layout.xml and the styles.xml. Sorry, I'm very new to this.

Comment: You need to modify the code that uses layuot.xml. It cannot be done without modifying the code

Comment: This is not fair, I put this answer earlier!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. To display parts of a TextView in different formats, you need [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html). Something like:

```
Spannable text = new SpannableString("bold, normal");    
text.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("bold"), 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

The id is just how you reference the TextView. The displayed text is referenced by "android:text" attribute.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm very new to this. this is the xml I'm talking about https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/jellybean/core/res/res/layout/keyguard_screen_tab_unlock.xml

Comment: So, maybe there's a way, to implement this here.